# Why does adding " rel='stylesheet' " stop local css file from loading in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I have a problem where I'm trying to to load a local css file (e.g. theme.css) as follows:

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

I am using Chrome (but I've tried in Microsoft Edge, as well), and the file won't load. It will be stuck as (pending) forever. If I remove the "rel" property than the file will load properly, without any problems.

I have been a developer for a few years now (although I haven't been working this low level for some time) and I don't remember ever encountering this problem.

I understand this might seem a bit inane for some, but I am very curious why this happens.

EDIT:

I am using Nodejs to return an using this code:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     var page = url.parse(req.url).pathname; 
    if (page == '/') {
        index = 0;
        fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
            res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
```

I think I am starting to understand the problem. Is it because I am using Nodejs to read an html file, and that file cannot dynamically return css files locally specified inside?

Comment: what chome version do u use?

Comment: Hmm odd. Are there any meta tags describing content rules? also can you try referencing the href like `/theme.css` (with a slash) and see if that works?

Comment: What do you see in devtools? In particular, any error or warning in the console? I'm thinking the server may be returning the file with the wrong `Content-Type` header.

Comment: (Side note: You don't need [`type`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#attr-link-type) on `link` and in most cases, don't want to specify it. Just make sure your server is configured correctly.)

Comment: @messerbill Version 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: @Webber I've tried. It didn't work. Meta tags describing content rules - I'm not sure what you're referring to. I am using a simple empty theme.css and script.js to load and they are not loading.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder 
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/script.js
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Provisional headers are shown
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36

This is everything I see. There are no errors. Type doesn't seem to affect in any way the outcome.

Comment: When you say 'local' what exactly do you mean here? Is it a localhost server? Or a local file:/// served straight from disk? Or...? Whatever it is are you sure (aka have you find into Dev tools and sanity checked it exactly)?

Comment: @ChrisM Yes, localhost. I'll edit my initial question with more details.

Comment: I edited my first answer to reflect the fact that I'm not sure HTTPS is relevant, or if it is, how. So, going back to first principles: if you have served the file by localhost then yes you won't be able to access files locally unless they too are served via a server. A relative URL like 'theme.css' will be served relative to the current host (in this case - localhost). Are you also serving your JS and CSS files via localhost?

Comment: Excuse me, are you sure you are not overwriting inline css rulers, defined inside html, with css rulers **with the same name** loaded by your external css file? Cause external files loads later than html, so if you have the same ruler loaded twice, the later will command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've realised what the problem was. Because I am using node.js to serve the server (in this case localhost) files, I needed to serve specifically the files in my requests (such as having a route to script.js and theme.css). I thought that simply returning the html that contains the files (locally) would suffice, since opening index.html would return the js and css files without any problem. I am not sure why rel="stylesheet" would affect whether the file could be loaded anyways.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Glad you were able to get to the bottom of this. Sounds like you were a bit confused about how html works - all the associated images, stylesheets etc of an html file are requested via seperate http requests and so yes they need their own URLs.

Comment: So how did you solve the problem? I have the exact same problem and I can't figure out how to load a custom css file. If I remove "rel" property my stylesheet would not load at all.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment the problem appears to be related to accessing a non https resource from https.

See this link about referer policy: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Importantly the section on integration with CSS:

> CSS can fetch resources referenced from stylesheets. These resources
>   are following a referrer policy as well.
>
> External CSS stylesheets use the default policy
>   (no-referrer-when-downgrade) unless it's overwritten via an HTTP
>   header that is set for a CSS stylesheet specifically.
>
> For inline styles or styles created from APIs like HTMLElement.style,
>   the owner document's referrer policy is used.

My guess is that when the rel attribute is set then it uses the default policy, but when it isn't then it uses the documents policy. This is a curious interaction and I'm not sure it's supposed to work like that.

---

EDIT: I can see from your update that you aren't using HTTPS, so I'm not sure why this would be relevant. The message in your comment definitely referenced the referrer policy, and I saw this and made a logical conclusion.

Now I'm not sure. For now I'm going to leave this answer and then I may delete it if another, correct, idea comes up

Comment: Thak you for the answer, but that doesn't answer why it also happens for my .js files. It might be because I'm using nodejs to read the file and return it (see updated question).

Comment: @VladfP Yes it would happen to your js files for the same reason. Are you using https in any of this?

Comment: @Rob No, using nodejs to return on localhost the html file that includes my css and js. The files are also locally, so no https is involved at all. I am very confused.

Comment: ChrisM mentions accessing a "non-https resource from http". Doesn't non-https just mean http? Why should there be a problem with that, since I'm running a local server on http, returning http resources?

Comment: @VladfP I just did some research based upon the comment you left (before I saw that you weren't using https), but having looked at it again I'm not at all sure. I think there might be a different issue at play here.

Comment: @VladfP "non-https resource from http" was supposed to be "non-https resource from https" - just a typo and I have corrected it.